# Rename duplicate rows

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql, common-table-expression, sql-update

Here's a simplified example of my problem. I have a table where there's a "Name" column with duplicate entries:

```
ID    Name
---   ----
 1    AAA
 2    AAA
 3    AAA
 4    BBB
 5    CCC
 6    CCC
 7    DDD
 8    DDD
 9    DDD
10    DDD
```

Doing a GROUP BY like `SELECT Name, COUNT(*) AS [Count] FROM Table GROUP BY Name` results in this:

```
Name  Count
----  -----
AAA   3
BBB   1
CCC   2
DDD   4
```

I'm only concerned about the duplicates, so I'll add a HAVING clause, `SELECT Name, COUNT(*) AS [Count] FROM Table GROUP BY Name HAVING COUNT(*) > 1`:

```
Name  Count
----  -----
AAA   3
CCC   2
DDD   4
```

Trivial so far, but now things get tricky: I need a query to get me all the duplicate records, but with a nice incrementing indicator added to the Name column. The result should look something like this:

```
ID    Name
---   --------
 1    AAA
 2    AAA (2)
 3    AAA (3)
 5    CCC 
 6    CCC (2)
 7    DDD 
 8    DDD (2)
 9    DDD (3)
10    DDD (4)
```

Note row 4 with "BBB" is excluded, and the first duplicate keeps the original Name.

Using an `EXISTS` statement gives me all the records I need, but how do I go about creating the new Name value?

```
SELECT * FROM Table AS T1 
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT Name, COUNT(*) AS [Count] 
    FROM Table 
    GROUP BY Name 
    HAVING (COUNT(*) > 1) AND (Name = T1.Name))
ORDER BY Name
```

I need to create an UPDATE statement that will fix all the duplicates, i.e. change the Name as per this pattern.

Update:
Figured it out now. It was the [PARTITION BY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx) clause I was missing.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
With Dups As
    (
    Select Id, Name
        , Row_Number() Over ( Partition By Name Order By Id ) As Rnk
    From Table
    )
Select D.Id
    , D.Name + Case
                When D.Rnk > 1 Then ' (' + Cast(D.Rnk As varchar(10)) + ')'
                Else ''
                End As Name
From Dups As D
```

If you want an update statement you can use pretty much the same structure:

```
With Dups As
    (
    Select Id, Name
        , Row_Number() Over ( Partition By Name Order By Id ) As Rnk
    From Table
    )
Update Table
Set Name = T.Name + Case
                    When D.Rnk > 1 Then ' (' + Cast(D.Rnk As varchar(10)) + ')'
                    Else ''
                    End
From Table As T
    Join Dups As D
        On D.Id = T.Id
```

Comment: I dig the CTEs.  I wish I'd use them more often.

Comment: @Jakob Gade- Are you getting an error or is it not producing the results you want?

Comment: I think I got it working now. I just had to figure out how to replace the "FROM Table" with the query I have for selecting just the rows I want to modify. :)

Comment: @Jakob Gade - Correct. It really is `From <insert your table name>`. In addition, you could filter on `Rnk > 1` although I've written the query such that rows where the Rnk = 1 are unaffected.

Answer (score 6):

Just update the subquery directly:

```
update d
set Name = Name+'('+cast(r as varchar(10))+')'
from    (   select  Name, 
                    row_number() over (partition by Name order by Name) as r
            from    [table]
        ) d
where r > 1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Name) AS RowNum,
       Name,
       Name + '(' + ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY Name) + ')' concatenatedName
FROM Table 
WHERE Name IN 
(
     SELECT Name 
     FROM Table 
     GROUP BY Name 
     HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
)
```

This will get you what you originally asked for.  For the update statement, you'll want to do a while and update the top 1

```
DECLARE @Pointer VARCHAR(20), @Count INT

WHILE EXISTS(SELECT Name FROM Table GROUP BY Name HAVING COUNT(1) > 1)
BEGIN
    SELECT TOP 1 @Pointer = Name, @Count = COUNT(1) FROM Table GROUP BY Name HAVING COUNT(1) > 1
    UPDATE TOP (1) TABLE
    SET Name = Name + '(' + @Count + ')'
    WHERE Name = @Pointer
END
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm going by memory.  I don't have SSMS on my laptop.  You could wrap the concatenated name in a case to remove the first (1).

Comment: Exellent, it works! Just had to add a CAST for the row number and the CASE as you suggested.

Comment: Thank you and sorry about forgetting the CAST.  Had I had SSMS installed here, I would have tested it.

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to do an `UPDATE` at all. The following will create the table for `INSERT` as desired

```
SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY tb2.Id) Id,
    tb2.Name + CASE WHEN COUNT(*) > 1 THEN ' (' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, Count(*)) + ')' ELSE '' END [Name]
FROM
    tb tb1,
    tb tb2
WHERE
    tb1.Name = tb2.Name AND
    tb1.Id <= tb2.Id
GROUP BY
    tb2.Name,
    tb2.Id
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an even simpler UPDATE statement:

```
UPDATE
    tb
SET
    [Name] = [Name] + ' (' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY [Name] ORDER BY Id)) + ')'
WHERE
    ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY [Name] ORDER BY Id) > 1
```

Comment: Thanks. But I tried it, but I can't get it to work. Error message says "Windowed functions can only appear in the SELECT or ORDER BY clauses."