# Dynamic sql pivot values coming in seperate columns

Tags: sql, dynamic, pivot, entity-attribute-value

HI I am trying to write dynamic pivot as I have over 100 columns

```
ID   Question    Answer
1    Name        peter
1    DOB         11/12/2003
1    address     …..
1    Issue1      d
1    Issue2      a
2    Name        sam
2    DOB         10/01/1998
2    address     …..
2    Issue1      p
2    Issue2      f
```

I want the output like this:

```
ID    Name    DOB         address    Issue1  Issue2
1     peter   11/12/2003    ….       d        a
2     sam     10/01/1998    ….       p        f
```

Here is the code that I have used:-

```
select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(Question) 
                from #temp
                FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
        ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
    ,1,1,'')

set @query = N'SELECT ID + @cols + N' 
            from #temp
        pivot 
        (
            max([answer])
            for Question in (' + @cols + N')
        ) p '

exec sp_executesql @query;
```

But I am getting each answer in a separate row. I want all the answers of an ID to come in one row. Can somebody help me. Appreciate your time on this. Thank you.

I am getting the output like this, which is not I want. I want the output as above.

```
ID    Name    DOB       address Issue1    Issue2
1     Peter             
1            11/12/2003         
1                       …       
1                               d   
1                                        a
```

Comment: "I want all the answers of an ID to come in one column".  I don't understand.  Your desired results have mutliple columns.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (That code is product specific.)

Comment: Hi Gordon, I have edited my above post with the output I am getting. I am using Sql 2008

Comment: Sorry, I typed column instead of row. I want all the answers for each id in one row. I am getting each answer in a different row. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are looking for a way to dynamically create a pivot based on your table without aggregation. You can try the following:

```
SELECT @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(Question) 
                    FROM #TEMP
                    GROUP BY QUESTION
                    ORDER BY QUESTION
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT ID,' + @cols + ' FROM 
             (
                SELECT ID, Question, Answer
                FROM #TEMP
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                MAX(Answer)
                for Question in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '

execute(@query);
```

Expected Output:

```
+----+---------+------------+--------+--------+-------+
| ID | address |    DOB     | Issue1 | Issue2 | Name  |
+----+---------+------------+--------+--------+-------+
|  1 | …..     | 11/12/2003 | d      | a      | peter |
|  2 | …..     | 10/1/1998  | p      | f      | sam   |
+----+---------+------------+--------+--------+-------+
```

Comment: That works perfect. Many thanks @Jiggles32. However, I have got another problem now. I have got a question with name 'parents' for each id where they have mother's name and father's name. With max(answer) in pivot, only one parent's name is coming up. How do I get 2 names or 2 names separated by comma is fine. Please help. Many thanks.

Comment: Or is there a way to rename them to parent1, parent2 and the names in 2 different columns

Comment: The only way I can think of how to do it is by renaming them in the base table. And the only reasonable way I can think of to do that is by duplicate row renaming like [this question suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5176218/rename-duplicate-rows). However, you may want to open another question line for this topic (if you need more specific help).

Comment: That's great. I will try implementing that.  Many thanks for your help @Jiggles32.